# Работа с консолью Gooogl Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, php

Подскажите есть ли какая то возможность работать с консолью Gooogl Chrome извне - выполнять скрипты, сохранять результаты действия скриптов в файл и т.д.

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста, что Вы понимаете под "работать с консолью Gooogl Chrome".

Comment: Чтобы я смог программно с ней работать а не из браузера т.е. извне. Пока нашел вот такое http://habrahabr.ru/post/141981/

Comment: Интересно зачем вам такое понадобилось?.. В любом случае

> WebSockets + eval

Comment: Нужно спарсить сайт, но там очень хитрая защита(javascript captcha и прочее) - из консоли я могу парсить, но только по одной странице и сохранять результат не могу.

Comment: Я так понимаю что в этом случае браузер будет выступать как веб сервер ?

Comment: Если можешь парсить из консоли, то спокойно можешь парсить и из обычного скрипта.

Comment: В том то и дело что не могу - нужно получить доступ к навигации страницы например чтобы переходить по ссылкам внутри сайта

Comment: Тогда - phantom.js вам в помощь :)